# Error while creating an upsert in rest webservice?

Tags: webservices, rest, apexrest, rest-service

Rest webservice for handling the json and inserting list of accounts inside salesforce, `email(external id)` is already present in the system then update the `account` else insert on `account` object with `record type  'Person Account'`

Code:

```
global with sharing class AccountWebService
{

 @HttpPost
  global static String doUpsert()
  {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        //system.debug('-----------data--------'+req) ;
        system.debug('-----------data--------'+req.requestBody.toString()) ;

    list<master> b = (list<master>)JSON.deserialize(req.requestBody.toString(),list<master>.class);

        system.debug('----------b----------'+b);

    list<Account> accList = new list<Account>();
        Account acc = new Account();

        if(!b.isEmpty())
        {

            for(master mas: b)
            {
                 Id regularShowId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.RecordTypeInfosByName.get('Person Account').RecordTypeId; 

                if(!string.isBlank(mas.MagentoID))   
                {
                    acc.Magento_ID__c = string.valueof(mas.MagentoID);
                }
                if(!string.isBlank(mas.fname))   
                {
                    acc.firstname= string.valueof(mas.fname);
                }
                if(!string.isBlank(mas.lname))   
                {
                    acc.lastname= string.valueof(mas.lname);
                }
                if(!string.isBlank(mas.Phon))   
                {
                    acc.Phone= string.valueof(mas.Phon);
                }
                if(!string.isBlank(mas.DateCustomerAdded))   
                {
                    acc.Date_Customer_Added__c = date.valueof(mas.DateCustomerAdded);
                }
                if(!string.isBlank(mas.Email))   
                {
                    acc.Email__c= string.valueof(mas.Email);
                }


                    //acc.Date_Customer_Added__c = datetime.valueof(mas.DateCustomerAdded);
                    acc.RecordtypeID = 'regularShowId';

                accList.add(acc);
            }   
                Database.UpsertResult[] upsertResult = Database.upsert(accList,Account.Email__c,false);

        }
        // return JSON.serialize(acc); 
        return 'Success';
  }

   global class master
   {
       public string MagentoID;
       public string fname;
       public string lname;
       public string Phon;
       public string Email; 

       public master()
       {

       }
   }

}
```

Comment: Exactly what error do you get and at exactly which line?

Comment: No error now, but Record is not getting created. When i tried using   RecordType personAccountRecordType =  [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Person Account' and SObjectType = 'Account'];   acc.RecordTypeId = personAccountRecordType.id;

Comment: Database.UpsertResult[] upsertResult = Database.upsert(accList,Account.Fields.Email__c,true);    Which is not working publicly.

Comment: This "not working publicly" doesn;t make much sense to me. If the upsert isn't working you can loop over the Database.UpsertResult objects and find the cause.

Comment: Works perfect......! Database.UpsertResult[] upsertResult = Database.upsert(accList,Account.field.Email__c,false);